# How to prevent cross site scripting in MVC when AJAX request is sent by another website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xss

I have an HTML form in MVC ASP.NET which the user fills out and the request goes to the server [AJAX] then we send a mail them to inform them.  I use the hidden key to store information on the page.

I find that someone changed the key and then clicked then it's a problem that the mail go to other who are unknown for this case.

How can I be sure that nobody changes the hidden key and request is valid. The thing I want to do that HTML. antioforeignkey who is suitable for that.

But how can I implement antiforeignkey when I send AJAX request to server.

Are there any tricks to solve this problem in MVC?

Comment: I think you might be confused about what cross site scripting is.  Cross site scripting is when someone can execute their script on your website.  As long as you sanitize all the input to your site you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/

This link will help with AntiForgeryToken and Ajax calls: http://blogs.us.sogeti.com/swilliams/2009/05/14/mvc-ndash-using-antiforgerytoken-over-ajax/

Be sure to add @Html.AntiForgeryToken() to your form then you can use jQuery to pull that value.  With the value you can then add it to the data attribute of your jQuery Ajax call.

```
var token = $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
```